# How to export a stateless functional component with styles in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I have a file named MyButtons.js from which I want to export two stateless functional components one of which contains a `style` variable. But I get the following error.

> path/to/MyButtons.js
>
> SyntaxError: path/to/MyButtons.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled (64:8):
>
> 64 | export withStyles(styles)({ AllButtonsRow, UDButtons, });

What am I doing wrong?

MyButtons.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const MyRegularButton = props => (<Button>Click me!</Button>);

const MyStyledButton = props => (<Button className={classes.button}>Click me!</Button>);

export withStyles(styles)({ MyRegularButton, MyStyledButton, });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `default` keyword :

```
export default withStyles(styles)({ MyRegularButton, MyStyledButton })
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to include the `default` keyword in your exports.
2. In order to access the classes that withStyles creates you need to access them through props by using `props.classes.button`
3. You also need to make sure that withStyles passes the `theme` property into your styles function. [By default this is set to false](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component). Without this you will not be able to access properties such as `theme.spacing.unit`.

In summary you need to change your final line to the following:

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })({ MyRegularButton, MyStyledButton })
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, you also need to add `classes` to the input `props` object as follows.

```
const MyStyledButton = ({ classes, }) => (...
```

So the entire file reads as follows. (Edit: Incorporated answer by @MattC)

MyButtons.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const MyRegularButton = props => (<Button>Click me!</Button>);

const MyStyledButton = ({ classes, }) => (
  <Button className={classes.button}>Click me!</Button>
);

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })({ MyRegularButton, MyStyledButton })
```