# Importing stateless functional components with styles in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jss

[When implementing this answer, I get the following error message.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54753694/1640892)

> Inbox.js:52 Error getting documents:
>
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `WithStyles(Component)`.

Inbox.js calls MyView.js. And MyView.js imports `<MyButtons/>`

MyView.js

```
import MyRegularButton from './MyButtons';
import MyStyledButton from './MyButtons';

<MyButtons />
```

What am I doing wrong?

MyButtons.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const MyRegularButton = props => (<Button>Click me!</Button>);

const MyStyledButton = ({ classes, }) => (
  <Button className={classes.button}>Click me!</Button>
);

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })({ MyRegularButton, MyStyledButton })
```

Comment: you cannot export default 2 component, although you can export them individually

Comment: @warl0ck: Can you provide an answer and an example of what that would look like in this case?

Comment: export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MyRegularButton)

Comment: @Mowzer I have answered with the example see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `Button.js` file you can export both components like

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const MyRegularButton = props => (<Button>Click me!</Button>);

const MyStyledButton = ({ classes, }) => (
  <Button className={classes.button}>Click me!</Button>
);

const Regular = withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MyRegularButton)
const StyledButton = withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true });(MyStyledButton);                                                       
export { Regular,StyledButton}
```

and then you can import it in different files like:

`import { Regular } from './Button'`

and

`import { StyledButton } from './Button'`